# Using Gnus + Gmail with Oauth2

Tags: gnus, email, smtpmail

I'm looking to use gmail with gnus, however my work has disabled app passwords, so the only way to connect to gmail is through oauth2 which is how I've done it with for example aerc mail.

I'm trying to find documentation for how to set up a new account with oauth2 authentication but I can't really find anything. Any guidance?

Comment: This seems to be a question about Gmail or about Oauth2, not about Emacs, no?

Comment: It's about using integrating gmail with gnus, the emacs email client using oauth2.

Comment: It's unclear that *"how to set up a new account with oauth2 authentication?"* is a question about Emacs.  Please explain.

Comment: It's specifically pertaining gnus, how can I connect an account with oauth2 in Gnus.

Comment: It's perfectly obvious what you are asking. Acccessing gmail from gnus using oauth2 security.